# How to run storybook with a Vue component library that is internally using .less files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, less, storybook

I'm trying to use [Nitrozen-vue](https://github.com/gofynd/nitrozen-vue/blob/master/src/components/NBtn/NBtn.vue) CSS component library (which is internally using .less for styling) in my storybook project (using Vue2)

I'm able to render the components on the storybook. However, for some reason, the styling isn't being applied.

I have added loaders inside my .storybook/main.js file like this:

[Webpack4]

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [require.resolve("vue-style-loader"), require.resolve("css-loader"), require.resolve("less-loader")],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

When I run storybook using

```
npm run storybook
```

it opens with a continuous loader on screen like this

[image]

How to run storybook with a Vue component library that is internally using .less files?